# CoreUI Chart type Bar- clickable bars to link to another page

Tags: reactjs, chart.js, core-ui

I'm looking to create a drilldown using the CChartBar available in the CoreUI documentation here: https://coreui.io/react/docs/3.3/components/CCharts/

I need to be able to get the month from the bar that is clicked, and when the bar is clicked, it needs to take the user to another page. How do I get the information? How to I make each bar clickable to send the user to the table page?

Currently here is the html

```
                <div className="chart-container">
                    <CChartBar
                    datasets={[
                      {
                        label: "Expected Expirations",
                        type: "bar",
                        data: expectedExpirations,
                        backgroundColor: "#949fe8",
                        borderColor: "blue",
                        fill: true,
                        order: 2,
                      },
                      {
                        label: 'Actual Expirations',
                        type: "bar",
                        data: actualExpirations,
                        backgroundColor: '#556ad1',
                        borderColor: "blue",
                        fill: true,
                        order: 1,
                      },
                      {
                        label: 'Target Expirations',
                        backgroundColor: '#352c2c',
                        data: targetExpirations,
                        type: "line",
                        borderColor: "black",
                        fill: true,
                        order: 0,
                        borderWidth: 2,
                        fill: "#352c2c",
                        pointBackgroundColor: "#352c2c",
                        lineTension: 0,
                      }
                    ]}
                      labels={dateLabels}
                      onClick={(event) => drillDown(event)}
                    options={{
                      maintainAspectRatio: false,
                      responsive: true,
                      tooltips: {
                        enabled: true,
                      },
                      scales: {
                        xAxes: [{
                          stacked: true,
                          scaleLabel: {
                            display: true,
                            labelString: "Month"
                          }
                        }],
                        yAxes: [{
                          ticks: {
                            stacked: true,
                            beginAtZero: true,
                            stepValue: 10,
                            max: maxOfAllExpirations
                          },
                          scaleLabel: {
                            display: true,
                            labelString: "Number of Lease Expirations"
                          }
                        }]
                      },
                    }}
                  />
```

[image: bar chart visual]

I would like to be able to click on the bar, and get the data that is being charted, so I can pass the month to another page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `onClick` function for this:

```js
var options = {
  type: 'bar',
  data: {
    labels: ["December 2020", "Januarie 2021", "Feb 2021", "March 2021", "April 2021", "May 2021"],
    datasets: [{
      label: '# of Votes',
      data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 3, 3],
      backgroundColor: 'pink'
    }]
  },
  options: {
    onClick: (evt, activeEls) => {
      console.log(activeEls[0]._model.label)
      console.log(activeEls[0]._model.label.split(" ")[0])
    }
  }
}

var ctx = document.getElementById('chartJSContainer').getContext('2d');
new Chart(ctx, options);
```

```html
<body>
  <canvas id="chartJSContainer" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.4/Chart.js"></script>
</body>
```

```
<div className = "chart-container" >
  <CChartBar
datasets = {
  [{
      label: "Expected Expirations",
      type: "bar",
      data: expectedExpirations,
      backgroundColor: "#949fe8",
      borderColor: "blue",
      fill: true,
      order: 2,
    },
    {
      label: 'Actual Expirations',
      type: "bar",
      data: actualExpirations,
      backgroundColor: '#556ad1',
      borderColor: "blue",
      fill: true,
      order: 1,
    },
    {
      label: 'Target Expirations',
      backgroundColor: '#352c2c',
      data: targetExpirations,
      type: "line",
      borderColor: "black",
      fill: true,
      order: 0,
      borderWidth: 2,
      fill: "#352c2c",
      pointBackgroundColor: "#352c2c",
      lineTension: 0,
    }
  ]
}
labels = {
  dateLabels
}
onClick = {
  (event) => drillDown(event)
}
options = {
  {
    onClick: (evt, activeEls) => {
      console.log(activeEls[0]._model.label)
      console.log(activeEls[0]._model.label.split(" ")[0])
    },
    maintainAspectRatio: false,
    responsive: true,
    tooltips: {
      enabled: true,
    },
    scales: {
      xAxes: [{
        stacked: true,
        scaleLabel: {
          display: true,
          labelString: "Month"
        }
      }],
      yAxes: [{
        ticks: {
          stacked: true,
          beginAtZero: true,
          stepValue: 10,
          max: maxOfAllExpirations
        },
        scaleLabel: {
          display: true,
          labelString: "Number of Lease Expirations"
        }
      }]
    },
  }
}
/>
``
```

Comment: So, this doesn't utilize the CChartBar component in the CoreUI, which is a requirement.

Comment: What do you mean you just add it in your options object which you already have

Comment: So, which part of the options? and the last line creating a new chart with the CTX and options? 

I'm not using chart.js, I'm using the CoreUI component that extends it, so the script part doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: There is only 1 options object in my code and in yours. Since coreui is using chart.js to draw it should work the same, same options object but see updated answer

Comment: I see now. Thank you! Still some tweaks to get it how I need it with a link, but I think I can manage that.